# php condition : first test of my inputs array ignored

Tags: php, html

I want to check the inputs of my inputs with conditions (if, else..) nothing very complicated so far. But the problem is that the first condition is never taken into account.

Here is the code of my form:

```
 <form method="POST" action="">
   <table>
      <caption>author :</caption>
      <?php
      for($i=1; $i <= $author; $i++){?>
      <tr>
         <td align="right">
            <label for="<?= 'author'.$i ?>"> <?='author '.$i ?> :</label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder=" nom du author" id=" <?= 'author'.$i ?>" name="authors[]">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <?php 
      }?>
   </table>
   <table>
      <caption>title :</caption>
      <?php 
      for($i=1; $i <= $title; $i++){?>
      <tr>
         <td align="right">
            <label for="<?= 'title'.$i ?>"> <?= 'title '.$i ?> :</label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder=" title" id="<?= 'title'.$i ?>" name="titles[]">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <?php 
      }?>
   </table>
   <table>
      <caption>article :</caption>
      <?php
      for($i=1; $i <= $article; $i++){?>
      <tr>
         <td align="right">
            <label for="<?= 'article'.$i ?>"> <?= 'article '.$i ?> :</label>
         </td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="ex: score possible(min:0)" id="<?= 'article'.$i ?>" name="articles[]">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="article" value="0">
         </td>
         <td align="right">
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="btnSusbmit" class="modal-btn modal-eventTrigger modal-reportEventTrigger" value="Next">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

and here is my php code :

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSusbmit']))
{
   if(!empty($_POST['authors']))
   {
      $_SESSION['authors'] = array_unique($_POST['authors']);
      if(!empty($_POST['titles']))
      {
         $_SESSION['titles'] = array_unique($_POST['titles']);
         if(!empty($_POST['articles']) and !empty($articles) and $articles != 0)
         {
            $_SESSION['articles'] = array_unique($_POST['articles']);
         }
         elseif(!empty($articles) and $articles != 0 and empty($_POST['articles']))
         {
            $error = 'all fields "articles" must be filled in.';
         }
      }
      else 
      {
         $error = 'all fields "titles" must be filled in.';
      }
   }
   else 
   {
      $error = 'all fields "authors" must be filled in';
   }
}
```

I transmuted the conditions to test and no matter the condition it is always the same problem.

Edit :

```
var_dump($POST] = array(5) { ["authors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["titles"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["articles"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" } ["article"]=> string(1) "0" ["btnSubmit"]=> string(7) "Next" }
```

Comment: You're talking about `if (isset($_POST['btnSusbmit']))`?

Comment: Can you edit your post with the content of $_POST after submitting? var_dump($_POST);

Comment: @Barmar no I'm talking if(!empty($_POST[authors]))

Comment: @Harkhenon I have just made the changes requested in my post.

Comment: The var_dump shows btnSubmit, elsewhere you have btnSusbmit. Are we not just talking about a typo?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, your form is missing a closing bracket to your last for loop:

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i <= $article; $i++){?>
```

You open it there but never close it.

Second, this is your first condition:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSusbmit']))
```

And it's just checking if theres any POST field with the name 'btnSusbmit', all your submits have this same name so if any of them have been clicked this will always evaluate to true

What i think you want to know is why this line:

```
if(!empty($_POST['authors']))
```

Is always returning true even when the 'author' fields are empty, and thats because even if you don't fill in your text inputs, the form is still creating an array with the empty strings. This is what comes out of a `var_dump` (i defined your variables as 5 just to get some test fields)

```
array (size=5)
  'authors' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
  'titles' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
  'articles' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
      3 => string '' (length=0)
      4 => string '' (length=0)
  'article' => string '0' (length=1)
  'btnSusbmit' => string 'Next' (length=4)
```

'authors' is never empty because even if you don't fill your texts, it is still an array that has elements inside, if you want to throw an error when the text inputs are left empty, then you need to check the strings inside the elements of the 'authors' array

Comment: But in this case why does it work for $_POST['titles'] ? And for $_POST['authors'] if it passes in 3rd condition that is to say instead of $_POST['titles'].

Comment: Running the code you gave both conditions always pass as true as long as there is atleast one input, regardless of changing their order and the text filled in the inputs. There might be another part of your code that is affecting the result if one of them returns as false for you in that case